# How to setup my CANbus message filterering acceptance code and mask?

Tags: esp32, can-bus

I have no success enabling the filtering configuration of the CANbus driver. The doc is right there (CTRL+F acceptance filter): https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v3.3/api-reference/peripherals/can.html#configuration

I would like to setup the filter so that I can only catch my extended frames which bear the ID that fall within 0x18000000 to 0x18FFFFFF range.

But my code does not catch the frames which I expect (aka 0x18307001).

I probably misunderstand the documentation.

My code is as follows:

```dart
    can_general_config_t general_config = {
        .mode = 
        //CAN_MODE_NO_ACK,
        //CAN_MODE_LISTEN_ONLY,
        CAN_MODE_NORMAL,
        
        .tx_io = (gpio_num_t)TXD,
        .rx_io = (gpio_num_t)RXD,
        .clkout_io = (gpio_num_t)CAN_IO_UNUSED,
        .bus_off_io = (gpio_num_t)CAN_IO_UNUSED,
        .tx_queue_len = 100,
        .rx_queue_len = 65,

        .alerts_enabled = CAN_ALERT_NONE,
        .clkout_divider = 0
    };
    log("CAN Driver: general config done");
    can_timing_config_t timing_config = CAN_TIMING_CONFIG_500KBITS();
    log("CAN Driver: timing config done @ 500KBPS");


    can_filter_config_t filter_config = 
    {
        .acceptance_code = 0x18FFFFFF, 
        .acceptance_mask = 0x00FFFFFF, //0x18FFFFFF, 
        .single_filter = true
    };
    log("CAN Driver: filter config done");

    esp_err_t error = can_driver_install(&general_config, &timing_config, &filter_config);
    #endif
```

Comment: It's not always obvious if setting a bit to 1 means don't care, or if it should be set to 0. Notably this whole masking crap was always causing more trouble than it solved and it was too blunt to be used for anything but very simple CAN nodes anyway. Modern CAN controllers (approx newer than year >2010) solve this with mailboxes instead, which is far more elegant in every way. Mailboxes also remove the need for crazy polling/interrupting to check every message/empty the Rx FIFO all the time. If you have the option to switch to a modern MCU then I would recommend doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution: I have to shift left 3 bits

```cpp
    const uint32_t acceptanceCode = 0x18000000U<<3;
    const uint32_t acceptanceMask = 0x00FFFFFFU<<3;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v3.3/api-reference/peripherals/can.html#configuration does not specify, how the mask has to be built.
I would expect from other implementations, that "don't care" bits have to be set to zero.

So, this should work:

```
acceptance_code = 0x18FFFFFF
acceptance_mask = 0x1F000000
```

Comment: If you are correct then that should be `0x1F000000`. Extended CAN frame identifiers are only 29 bits long.